# SUM of multiple products

Tags: sql, sum

I'm really struggling with this one. SO I have 2 tables:

- Products
- PendingCartItems

Here's a screenshot of structure for both tables:

[image: Products]

[image: PendingCartItems]

I need to get the SUM for all 3 products `WHERE pending_cart_id = 18`.

```
SELECT SUM(price) as TotalCartPrice FROM products WHERE id = '274'
```

How can I write it so it sums all 3 id's (274+251+49)?

Comment: Hint:  `IN` can be used instead of `=`.

Comment: Or at least use `or`, i.e. `id = ... or id = .. or id = ...`

Comment: Isn't this what joins are for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this not work?

```
Select sum(b.price*a.quantity)
  from pending_cart_items a
  join products b
    on a.product_id=b.id
 where a.pending_cart_id =18
```

**Edit:** Just realized I'd omitted the quantity from the cart computation :)

Comment: Yup, this is it. And I also forgot about the quantity. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to join the two tables:-

```
select
  sum(p.price)
from Products p
  inner join PendingCartItems pci on p.id= pci.product_id
where pci.pending_cart_id = 18
```

Comment: I think this is backwards - i think price comes from products - and you have to take into account quantity if it's more then one as `sum(p.price * pci.quantity)

Comment: Ah..assumed the order of the images was the same as the order of the tables listed.

Answer (score 0):

If the model is relational, you can try this

```
SELECT
SUM(price) as TotalCartPrice
FROM products
INNER JOIN PendingCartItems ON products.id = PendingCartItems.product_id
WHERE PendingCartItems.pending_cart_id = 18
GROUP BY PendingCartItems.pending_cart_id
```